# Karate - To find array indices of multiple occurance of an element in a JSON response array

Tags: karate

I have a JSON response from an endpoint that gives me a nested array of elements. And given an input value, I want to find out all the index values where this value occurs and not just the first occurance of the element.

For example here is the response I have:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "vin": "MMTestingVIN00002",
            "dealerCode": "1",
            "nmscCode": "1",
            "warning": {
                "warningLightType": {
                    "code": 1,
                    "description": "",
                    "symbol": "OLW",
                    "type": "S",
                    "priority": "1"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "vin": "HESQM0IBWUR7DH0DU",
            "dealerCode": "1",
            "nmscCode": "1",
            "warning": {
                "warningLightType": {
                    "code": 1,
                    "description": "",
                    "symbol": "OLW",
                    "type": "S",
                    "priority": "1"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "vin": "MMTestingVIN00002",
            "dealerCode": "1",
            "nmscCode": "1",
            "warning": {
                "warningLightType": {
                    "code": 1,
                    "description": "",
                    "symbol": "OLW",
                    "type": "S",
                    "priority": "1"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "vin": "ZCADWKEQM1GEADEQR",
            "dealerCode": "1",
            "nmscCode": "1",
            "warning": {
                "warningLightType": {
                    "code": 1,
                    "description": "",
                    "symbol": "WASH",
                    "type": "S",
                    "priority": "1"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "vin": "H5QGE06R54B8KYOUV",
            "dealerCode": "1",
            "nmscCode": "1",
            "warning": {
                "warningLightType": {
                    "code": 1,
                    "description": "",
                    "symbol": "WASH",
                    "type": "S",
                    "priority": "1"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to find out the indices where the arrays with `"vin = MMTestingVIN00002"` occurs.

I looked at https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/demos/js-arrays.feature for ideas. Also looked at other SO answers and tried:

```
* def VIN = 'MMTestingVIN00002'
* def response = result.items
* def names = $[*].vin
* def index = names.indexOf(VIN)
* print index
```

This gives the only the first occurance with the index 0. Ideally I want a result array index[] which gives [0,2] as result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
* def indexes = []
* def fun = function(x, i){ if (x.vin == 'MMTestingVIN00002') karate.appendTo(indexes, i) }
* karate.forEach(response.items, fun)
```